# Warning: Control may reach end of non-void function

Tags: c, recursion

This is a recursive function that converts binary numbers (given as arrays of integers) into decimals.

```
double binaryToDecimalRecursive(int *binary, int len) {
    if (len == 0) 
        return *binary;
    if (len > 0) {
        return (binary[0]*pow(2, len))+binaryToDecimalRecursive(binary+1, len-1);
    }
}
```

The GCC compiler gives me the "*control may reach end of non-void function*" warning.

What should I fix to prevent that?

Comment: What does your function return when `len < 0`?

Comment: It's not supposed to get that kind of input @kaylum

Comment: You should change the first if to if(len <= 0) just in case, then make the other if an else.

Comment: I've added a `if(len < 0) return -1;` but it still outputs me the warning

Comment: Looks like the compiler doesn't work out that the independent `if` conditions cover all the cases. Your options are to make the multiple `if` blocks into a single `if/else if/else`. Or have an unconditional `return` at the end of the function.

Comment: I'm compiling on a Mac, could that be a possible issue? I know that warnings are compiler/OS related, but this is not a very complex function.
I've tried using if/else with all the cases but that still doesn't solve the issue.

Comment: @matt95: If "It's not supposed to get that kind of input" why are you even using a *signed* integer type?

Comment: It's just a simple exercise, I didn't make it so perfect, that's why. But you're right @AnT

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like from the comments you've changed your code to be something like this, correct?

```
double binaryToDecimalRecursive(int *binary, int len) {
    if (len == 0) 
        return *binary;
    if (len > 0) {
        return (binary[0]*pow(2, len))+binaryToDecimalRecursive(binary+1, len-1);
    }
    if(len < 0) return -1;
}
```

The compiler doesn't recognize that it will always follow at least one of these branches. You can make it more explicit a few ways. Here is one way that should work:

```
double binaryToDecimalRecursive(int *binary, int len) {
    if (len == 0) 
        return *binary;
    else if (len > 0) { // Added an `else` statement
        return (binary[0]*pow(2, len))+binaryToDecimalRecursive(binary+1, len-1);
    }
    else return -1; // Here too
}
```

Comment: I guess the `else return -1` did it!

Comment: @matt95 See my answer for another possible solution.

Answer (score 1):

If `len < 0`, the function return nothing.
You should add a clause with `abort()` if it's smaller than `len` or simply return a default value.

Comment: That does not solve the problem. It still outputs the warning

Answer (score 1):

The compiler is complaining because you are using a non-void function, which must return a value. In C, you must have a value returned. Right now, if `len` is less than zero, the function would not return a value, which is not allowed.

Luckily, there is an easy fix. If there is no circumstance in which `len` will be less than zero, you can declare it as an `unsigned int` -- since an unsigned integer value cannot be less than zero, then your function will cover all possible input values of `len`. If `len` **can** be less than zero, then you need to `abort()` or return an error code to communicate to the caller of the function that invalid input was given.

Comment: The abort() function in a `if(len<0)` does not solve the issue. I still get the warn after that fix.

Comment: @matt95 Technically, it shouldn't issue that warning. I'd simply add a `return` statement then.

Answer (score 0):

The compiler is complaining because you are using a non-void function and the compiler doesn't know ahead of time that either of two conditions if(len == 0) and if(len > 0) will always be fulfilled. Basically it wants you to have a default return value that doesn't depend on any conditionals, so if somehow you messed up your logic and it *does* pass *both* conditionals, the program still has something to return. i.e. you always need a return that does not depend on any conditionals.

A good fix might be to have if(len < 0){ abort() }, and take out if(len > 0) so that becomes the default condition.

```
double binaryToDecimalRecursive(int *binary, int len) {
    if (len == 0) {
        return *binary;
    }
    if (len < 0){
    // I assume your program should never logically reach this condition, so this will be good for debugging. It will be more obvious that you reached an unwanted condition than if you returned -1
        abort();
    }
    // since we have specified actions for len <= 0, this is the equivalent of saying len > 0 without letting the compiler complain about it
    return (binary[0]*pow(2, len))+binaryToDecimalRecursive(binary+1, len-1);
}
```

Comment: That can't be done since I have to return a value that will be stored in a variable. I can't simply put a `return #` at the end of the function cause that would overwrite the decimal number that I need.

Comment: Not what I was suggesting at all. It's simply a matter of rewriting the same logic in a 'safer' way.

Comment: By the way - this may solve your 'control may reach end of non-void' error but your logic also needs rethinking. Why are you using an int* for binary and returning a double?

Comment: Because the pow() function returns a double value, and since I multiply it by an integer the final result should be a double. In the end I would have made a (int) cast to the value since I just need to get decimals.

Answer (score 0):

The proper solution for your problem, judging from the additional details you provided in the comments, is to use an *unsigned* integer type and get rid of `if (len > 0)` check entirely

```
double binaryToDecimalRecursive(const unsigned *binary, unsigned len) {
    return len == 0 ? 
        *binary :
        binary[0] * pow(2, len) + binaryToDecimalRecursive(binary + 1, len - 1);
}
```

Use unsigned integer types whenever you can, use signed integer types only when you have to.

P.S. Why do you refer to `binary[0]` as `*binary` in one place and as `binary[0]` in another? Is there a reason for such stylistic mishmash in such a small function?

Answer (score 0):

After having done this kind of work now for almost 40 years, I would personally
do it in a simpler and more straight forward way:

Since we want an int output,

```
long BinarytoDecimal(int binary[], int len)
   {
     int i, index;

     long result;

/**/              - I refer to this as the point of demarcation

     result = 0;
     for (i = 0, index = len; i < len; i++, index--)
        {
          result += (long) binary[i] * (long) pow(2,index);
        }

     return(result);
   }
```

As it is difficult to tell, when someone uses recursion to implement a loop,
this should (and I emphasize should, I think) give you the same result.

Comment: Thanks for your code.
I wrote the recursive function only because it was requested me to do so. Otherwise I would have made a common function which is always more straight forward.

Answer (score 0):

matt95,

thought you might be interested. I went ahead and try both sets of code using
GCC, on windows7, under cygwin, and they both DO give identical results for the
same input. The biggest difference, of course, that the code I wrote could not
possibly cause a 'code reaches end of non-void function' error.

```
                               Blake Mitchell
```